# Working with a remote GUI application

Tags: ubuntu, x11, vnc

I'm a not so experienced user of Linux systems and here's the thing I'm trying to achieve: I want to run a graphical application on a remote Linux (Ubuntu in particular) server, with an ability to connect to this application from Windows/Android at any time. The application should be running even if there are no active connections to it. Google suggests that I need a VNC server and client for this, however, the guides I've found so far seem complicated for my knowledge, and I simply don't know where to start. Could you please suggest the steps I am to take? Do I need a VNC server, or can I just use the ssh's X forwarding? Do I need to set up an actual X server? I'll post any details or configs if required.

Comment: By the rules of this site, this post is off-topic.  But the answer to your question is pretty straightforward: you probably want a VNC server, which is usually just as easy as: installing a desktop environment (e.g. Gnome), then installing VNC and enabling the service.  X11 forwarding over SSH is usually not a good choice as it is slow and has high overhead, but it can work in some scenarios.  This solution only requires (counter-intuitively) installing an X11 server on the *client*.

Comment: Questions that are too broad are generally a bad fit for [se] sites so this question will likely be closed on that basis. I'd suggest taking the [tour] and for future questions reading [ask] and [help].

Comment: Other queue reviewers: while this question is too broad, I think the cited close reason is another example of https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3892/22812

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan thank you for taking the time to post all those links. I'd say that I'm requesting not some "reading materials", but rather just the names of the tools I can use to achieve what I'm looking for. I think I'll deal with finding the materials I need right after I know what exactly I'm looking for.

Comment: IMO this is both too broad, and off topic because it's about VNC client programs for windows.

Comment: @cas well, it's not at all about the client programs. I've mentioned my most used OSes just to complete the picture. Anyway, I've achieved what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that there are two types of VNC servers for Linux: one type usually integrates with your desktop environment and can be used to access your *current* GUI session remotely.

Another type sets up a completely separate *seat*: a virtual display+keyboard+mouse combination that can be accessed *only* through VNC, and will have a login session that is completely independent of the session on the Linux system's local display.

The first type may be the easiest to set up: you probably won't need to do more than:

- install the appropriate VNC server package
- start the VNC server control application or desktop widget
- configure the VNC access password for your session and enable VNC remote access (preferably in this order!)
- allow incoming VNC connections to pass the software firewall, if you got one configured

You may find old instructions for installing a VNC server "from scratch": this is way more complex and usually not required any more, as most distributions have pre-packaged VNC servers available.

The second type of VNC server may be a bit more complicated to set up, but allows the remote session to live on independently of any local logins/logouts.

Comment: Thank you. This comment and some advice from different sources got me to where I wanted.